# Calculate Bayes (conditional probability array) using numpy

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

Am trying to code using numpy (no for loop pls) to calculate conditional probability between two matrices.

[]1=[1,0,1,0,1]  # sample array in 2 dimensional array X
=[1,1,1,1,−1]  # Y is boolean outcome and we are to find conditional probability vector X[i] when Y is 1

Expected outcome is
then  ([]1=1|=1)= (1+0+1+0)/4 =0.5  #sum of X[i] where i is indices of [Y==1] divide by number of times Y is 1
and  ([]1=1|=−1)= (1)/1 = 1

Numpy code am trying but not getting there..
pos = np.mean(Y==1)
neg = np.mean(Y==-1)

I am trying to use np.mean , np.sum functions without using for loop. i understand the algorithm but unable to implement using numpy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
x = np.array([1,0,1,0,1])
y = np.array([1,1,1,1,-1])

P = (x[y==1] == 1).mean()
```

Output: `0.5`

Intermediates:

```
x[y==1]
# array([1, 0, 1, 0])

(x[y==1] == 1)
# array([ True, False,  True, False])
```